# Suspend desktop shortcut doesn't work on lock screen

Tags: 18.04, suspend

The power button is set to suspend the laptop. But it doesn't work on the lock screen. I am using Kubuntu 18.04 with sddm as the display manager.

This is my configuration: [image]
So being a system setting, its a global shortcut, I believe.

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: "The power button is set to suspend the laptop." How exactly is this set? Is it defined as a global desktop shortcut? Please improve your question to describe exactly what isn't working for you.

Comment: @Murphy Edited.